# Create background sound for video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file without sound and a stereo audio file. Video is several times longer than audio. I'd like to create a background sound which starts from 2 second silence, then trim silence of the audio at both ends and duplicate trimmed audio several times to the end of the video.

[image]

I found how to trim audio:

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio.wav -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-75dB,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-75dB,areverse trimmed_audio.wav
```

And how to create silence:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000:duration=2 silence.wav
```

How can I duplicate the audio and combine it with the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic syntax is

`ffmpeg -an -i video -stream_loop -1 -i trimmed_audio.wav -af adelay=2000:all=1 -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M out.mp4`

Use ffmpeg 4.1 or newer.

Comment: Thank you!. Can you explain how it works? Can I use `silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-75dB,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-75dB,areverse` instead of `trimmed_audio.wav` to make everything in one line?

Comment: No. Then the silence will have to be removed for each iteration. This is cleaner.

Comment: If I don't want to reencode video will it be ok to add `c:v copy` to the end? `ffmpeg -an -i video -stream_loop -1 -i trimmed_audio.wav -af adelay=2000:all=1 -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M -c:v copy out.mp4`

Comment: Sure, -c:v copy is fine.